# General good practice folder structure for React + Nodejs (also to deploy on heroku)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, heroku, react-fullstack

I'm just practising building a fullstack project with Node (Express + GraphQL that connects to a MongoDB database on MongoDB Atlas cloud service) and React. I've separated my Node (Express) server files in a `server` folder, and React app in a `client` folder.

Here's my project directory overview:

[image]

Inside my `server` folder (Node + Express server):

[image]

Inside my `client` folder (React app):

[image]

Clearly I haven't thought in advance about how to best structure the project files and folders (taking into account the two questions below). So I have the following 2 questions:

1- I know there's no one way of doing things, but given the simplicity of this project, that it's developed by only me. What is a good practice for project folders and files directory arrangement of this scnario in general, taking into account git version control (i.e. 1 git repo in the root to keep track of all changes (but then do I have to place gitignore files in each of `client` and `server folders` and will it work?) or have git repo in each of the `server` and `client` folders?

2. Given that server application `app.js` is not in the root directory for heroku's `Procfile` to detect, how to best solve this?

I've read some previous forums about this, but they're a bit old, so I didn't know if things have changed since.